# Reading on-going process output from stdout using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I want to read on-going output of started process from code (running in background) with subprocess.Popen() and subprocess.communicate()

Starting the process:

```
import subprocess
process_params = ['/usr/bin/tcpdump', '-n', 'dst port 80']

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    process_params,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
```

The tcpdump process is running in background but proc.communicate() waits till end of file and only when process is killed it produces some output.

```
>>> (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
```

I would like to achieve something like receiving data from process' stdout at the moment when output is produced by the process.
I think I need some thread that looks if some output is generated from process and then for example append it to log file.
I don't know how to get down to it, so any ideas and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49209440/7738328. There the `stdout` stream is caught in a thread and modified before written to a log. That is similar to your use case, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

`tcpdump` is probably buffering its output. It will only write output when it has a buffer full of data (typically 8KB) to write. This is common behavior for programs which are not writing to a TTY.

Tcpdump has a command-line option to line-buffer its output. This causes it to write its output every time it has a full line of text. Try this:

```
process_params = ['/usr/bin/tcpdump', '-l', '-n', 'dst port 80']
                                       ^^--Line buffer output
```

Alternately, see if you have programs named `stdbuf` or `unbuffer` installed on your system. They can be used to adjust the buffering behavior of another process. Or see these questions:

- [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465619/13317)
- [How to unbuffer stdout of legacy running binary without stdbuf and similar tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45460998/13317)

Comment: While this is true, making tcpdump unbuffered will not fix the issue, since p.communicate won't return until the subprocess finishes. Thus, there is still the need for a threaded solution, for the `stdout` output.

Comment: Thanks Kenster for your idea of -l parameter, with combination of JohanL answer the tcpdump output is correctly saving to file :)